# How to configure mod_proxy to block every site except one

Tags: proxy, apache, mod-proxy

I'm trying to set up mod proxy to block all traffic except to a specific domain. I can configure it to block individual domains using the ProxyBlock  directive, and I can block everything using ProxyBlock *. Is there a way to block everything but one domain?

Thanks,

-Andrew

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On apache 2.2 you need to have 2 `proxy` sections.

```
ProxyRequests On
ProxyVia On

# block all domains except our target
<ProxyMatch ^((?!www\.proxytarget\.com).)*$>
   Order deny,allow
   Deny from all
</ProxyMatch>

# here goes your usual proxy configuration...
<ProxyMatch www\.proxytarget\.com >
   Order deny,allow
   Deny from all
   Allow from 127.0.0.1
</ProxyMatch>
```

On apache 2.4 it would be much easier because you could use the [If directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#if) instead of that regexp to invert the match for the domain name.

Note: I got that regexp from [Invert match with regexp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/957379/invert-match-with-regexp)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
ProxyBlock *
ProxyPass <path> <destination>
```

See if that works.

EDIT: scratch that. I think you have to get creative here with mod_rewrite (the basic reference is at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/proxy.html):

```
RewriteCond  %{HTTP_HOST}    =allowtoproxy.com
RewriteRule  ^/(.*)$         http://proxytarget.com/$1 [P]
ProxyPassReverse / http://proxytarget.com/
```

Try that?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
RewriteEngine On
# Testing URLs
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !google.co.uk [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !bbc.co.uk [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !amazon.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !centos.org [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !opensuse.org [NC]
# Url to redirect to if not in allowed list
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.org/notallowed.htm
```

Answer (score 0):

Apache 2.4: this worked for me: deny everything first then grant selectively.

```
ProxyRequests On
ProxyVia Off
AllowCONNECT 443 563 80

<Proxy *>
    Require all denied
</Proxy>

<ProxyMatch "^https?://[a-z]*\.?google\.com.*$">
    Require all granted
</ProxyMatch>

<ProxyMatch "^[a-z]*\.?google\.com:443$">
    Require all granted
</ProxyMatch>
```

Note the second ProxyMatch (with the :443) is required for HTTPS because else your request gets:

```
Received HTTP code 403 from proxy after CONNECT
```

meaning your https went through, but the SSL tunnel is rejected.

This works with Apache listening on :80, using the following request

> curl -x localhost:80 "https://www.google.com?q=mod_proxy&language=de"

but not with

> curl -x localhost:80 "https://www.bing.com?q=google.com"

which is essential, because otherwise you can circumvent the whitelisting by means of a bogus querystring parameter.