# apache2 forward proxy to restrict specific external ips to specific client ip's?

Tags: proxy, apache2, client, forward, restrict

Suppose I want the following clients to access only specific internet
servers from behind a apache2 forward proxy:

```
Client-1-IP: www.google.com
Client-2-IP: www.gmail.com
Client-3-IP: www.cnn.com
Client-4-IP: www.chess.com
```

Is this possible? I am running Apache 2.4.10 on Debian 8. Currently,
I am allowing specific clients to access the entire internet via this
configuration values, but want to be able to specify that a specific
client can access only a specific internet server:

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
        ProxyRequests On
        Proxyvia On
        <Proxy "*">
                Order deny,allow
                Deny from all
                Allow from <ip-1>
                Allow from <ip-2>
                Allow from <ip-3>
        </Proxy>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

just FYI this has been elaborated on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6129495/how-to-configure-mod-proxy-to-block-every-site-except-one), among other threads. In my case I wanted to configure an Apache 2.4 server to act as a forward proxy for a Maven on another machine without access to the Internet. Note that the restriction syntax has changed in Apache 2.4, so Allow/Deny/Order keywords should be replaced by Require clause as explained [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html). For example, let's suppose we want our proxy to listen on myhost.com:7775 and allow access only for 192.168.1.1 and to forward only to *.maven.org or *.apache.org. Then we would need the following in vhosts configuration (i suppose there may be an easier way to combine multiple allowed remote hosts):

```
<VirtualHost myhost.com:7775>
    ProxyRequests On
    ProxyVia On

    # block all domains except our target
    <ProxyMatch ^((?!maven\.org).)*$>
        Require all denied
    </ProxyMatch> 

    <ProxyMatch ^((?!apache\.org).)*$>
        Require all denied
    </ProxyMatch> 

    # only allow our IP for a specific target
    <ProxyMatch maven\.org >
        Require ip 192.168.1.1
    </ProxyMatch>  

    <ProxyMatch apache\.org >
        Require ip 192.168.1.1
    </ProxyMatch>  

</VirtualHost>
```