# Clear variables from workspace with exceptions by use of regular expressions

Tags: regex, matlab, variables

I'd like to clear all variables from workspace, but with some exceptions defined by regular expressions.

The function `clear` has an additional option `-regexp`

> `clear -regexp expr1 ... exprN` clears all variables that match any of
>   the regular expressions listed. This option only clears variables.

So I'm looking for the opposite.

Also there is

> `clearvars -regexp p1 p2 ...` clears all variables that match regular
>   expression patterns p1, p2, and so on.
>
> `clearvars -except v1 v2 ...`
>   clears all variables except for those specified following the -except
>   flag.

Which is already quite nice for complete variable names, but not working for regexp like the first option.

There are solutions on FEX, but I don't want to use additional custom functions.

**But As there are such convenient solutions for the just slightly different cases above, I wonder if there is also a simple way to do:**

`keep -regexp expr1 ... exprN`

with inbuilt functions.

Comment: `clearvars` supports regex for both matches and exclusions. See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/sco1/44ba551eecc942668c4c)

Comment: Thanks for the hint! Though I don't know if that's a new feature, its inclusion in the doc certainly is. Otherwise the whole question would have been obsolete :)

Comment: To be honest it doesn't look very well documented in the current documentation either. Comparing the [R2013a doc](http://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2013a/matlab/ref/clearvars.html) with the [current doc](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/clearvars.html) they both only show the `-regexp` flag for either the variable scope *or* the exclusions, not for both. I'll probably submit an enhancement request.

Comment: the current one has the line *Name Variables to Clear and Preserve Variables Using Regular Expressions* - quite clear. Does the old one contain that line? I don't have access to the old doc at home. But actually it doesn't really matter... ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/957379/invert-match-with-regexp) for inverse regexp matching. In this context:

```
clear -regexp ^((?!expr1|expr2|...).)*$
```

`clearvars` is not built-in, but an m-function, which has its own disadvantages. With the inverse regexp matching, you can do everything with `clear` (a built-in).