# Replace all besides the Regex group?

Tags: javascript, regex

I was given a task to do which requires a long time to do.

The image say it all :

This is what I have : (x100 times):

[image]

And I need to extract this value only

[image]

How can I capture the value ?

I have made it with this regex :

`DbCommand.*?\("(.*?)"\);`

As you can see it does work :

[image]

And **after** the `replace` function (`replace to $1`) I do get the pure value :

[image]

but the problem is that I need **only** the **pure** values and not the rest of the unmatched group :

**Question** : In other words :

How can I get the purified  result like :

```
Eservices_Claims_Get_Pending_Claims_List
Eservices_Claims_Get_Pending_Claims_Step1
```

[**Here is my code at Online regexer**](http://regexr.com?37ib3)

- Is there any way of replacing "all besides the matched group" ?

*p.s. I know there are other ways of doing it but I prefer a regex solution ( which will also help me to understand regex better)*

Comment: RegexBuddy would do this...also running it through visual studio would give you what you want...  Your link didn't work so I can't help much more than that.

Comment: @abc123 please read my PS

Comment: I meant using Regex...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Invert match with regexp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/957379/invert-match-with-regexp)

Comment: @abc123 Visual studio regex search engine is far stupid than JS regex engine. FYI

Comment: @abc123 nice one. I've tried this :http://regexr.com?37ibc. but is there a way of getting the inner group only with the already used regex ?

Comment: That site doesn't work for me...i'm sorry if I can't help further...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do a global replace of:

```
public static DataTable.*?{.*?DbCommand.*?\("(.*?)"\);.*?}
```

All I've done is changed it to match the whole block including the function definition using a bunch of `.*?`s.

Note: Make sure your regex settings are such that the dot (`.`) matches *all* characters, including newlines.

---

In fact if you want to close up all whitespace, you can slap a `\s*` on the front and replace with `$1\n`:

```
\s*public static DataTable.*?{.*?DbCommand.*?\("(.*?)"\);.*?}
```

Using your test case: http://regexr.com?37ibi

Comment: so it should be `[\s\S]`

Comment: @RoyiNamir Sure, or use the "dotall" option (in JavaScript I believe this is the `s` flag)

Comment: My way of thinking is to the group and then exclude all beside it....(without searching the exclude)

Comment: p.s. there is a checkbox dotall in the online tool

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, JavaScript doesn't understand [lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). If it did, you could change your regular expression to match `.*?` preceded (lookbehind) by `DbCommand.*?\("` and followed (lookahead) by `"\);`.

With that solution denied, i believe the cleanest solution is to perform two matches:

```
// you probably want to build the regexps dynamically
var regexG = /DbCommand.*?\("(.*?)"\);/g;
var regex  = /DbCommand.*?\("(.*?)"\);/;
var matches = str.match(regexG).map(function(item){ return item.match(regex)[1] });

console.log(matches); 
// ["Eservices_Claims_Get_Pending_Claims_List", "Eservices_Claims_Get_Pending_Claims_Step1"]
```

DEMO: http://jsbin.com/aqaBobOP/2/edit

Answer (score 1):

You can use this (without the ignore case and multiline option, with a global search):

```
pattern: (?:[^D]+|\BD|D(?!bCommand ))+|DbCommand [^"]+"([^"]+)
replace: $1\n
```

Answer (score 0):

Try simply replacing the whole document replacing using this expression:

```
^(?: |\t)*(?:(?!DbCommand).)*$
```

You will then only be left with the lines that begin with the string `DbCommand`

You can then remove the spaces in between by replacing:
    `\r?\n\s*` with `\n` globally.

Here is an example of this working: http://regexr.com?37ic4

Comment: this will not yield purifed results.