# regix match words starting with dot but exclude some

Tags: regex, nginx

I need to build regex to match all words starting with . but also white flag words like `.well-known` .. or some similar..

For now I have build the one that's complete opposite,, this one captures ONLY this one. I tried to find some regex symbol for invert but that doesn't exist I think..

```
location ~ /^(\.well-known) {
    deny all;
}
```

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an expression that works:

```
^(\.(?!well-known|other-forbidden-words|another-forbidden-word).+)$
```

Simply change the other words to white-listed words you want, and add more if need be.

Comment: thanx man,, now it's great :) https://regex101.com/r/mS2wC6/3 this regex stuff rocks

Comment: It does indeed. Regex is very powerful but a pain in the bloody arse.

Answer (score 0):

hm,,

I guess that I found my answer thanks to:

[Invert match with regexp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/957379/invert-match-with-regexp)

this is the test that works now:

https://regex101.com/r/mS2wC6/2

and solution is this:

```
^(\.(?!well-known))
```

so ok, I think I got this grouping thing now..

hth, k

Comment: Your expression isn't matching the whole word when it finds one that starts with `.` and isn't white-listed.

Comment: The `^(\.(?!well-known))` is the same as `^\.(?!well-known)` - unless you are using Group 1.

Answer (score 0):

well you don't have to add words in OR "|" condition 
you can simply do

```
$pattern = "/\.+(?:[a-zA-Z]|-)/";
```

which accepts anything that starts with . and contains - or alphabets.